# copying files from server to local automatically using batch command

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy the particular logfile generated for each day in one of my server which i have access to my local daily automatically.

I prepared the batch commands as follows but didn't work as expected.

echo off

```
SET logfiles=\\PWWAS0015\UMS_Logs\server1\ums\service-*.log
rem set var = C:\Users\L068699\Desktop\test\src
echo %logfiles%
copy %logfiles%  C:\Users\L068699\Desktop\test\

set yesterday = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd")
echo %yesterday%
pause
```

The problem is that I cana ble to extract all the logs but couldn't get the log which are like service-2015-04-17.log. How can I extract this kind of log which are one day behind i.e. if today is 2015-04-24 I should get the previous day log file service-2015-04-23.log

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
pushd \\PWWAS0015\UMS_Logs\server1\ums\
rem set var = C:\Users\L068699\Desktop\test\src
::echo service-*.log



for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"`) do set yesterday=%%a
echo %yesterday%
copy service-%yesterday%.log C:\Users\L068699\Desktop\test\
pause
```

Eventually you'll need NET command to map the network drivre:

```
NET USE  \\PWWAS0015\UMS_Logs /PERSISTENT:YES
```

(put the net use before the pushd if it does not work)

Comment: Thanks mate for the reply. But I am getting the log files copied to my test folder from 9th of this month to till now. I just want the yesterday's log only which should be service-2015-04-23.log to my test folder.

Comment: @user3259712 - just give me a few minutes

Comment: Thanks mate but using the recent one I am getting service-150422.log which is not there in that server location and as a result the command prompt showing system can't find the file specified. It should search as service-2015-04-22.log which will be available there. can we able to copy this pattern?

Comment: Soory mate it's not changed.. I have mentioned this initially also. I want only the previous day logfiles to be copied to my local automatically and logfiles format it would copy from my server location should be service-2015-04-23.log
as there are several other logs available in that location like service.log,service-db.log,service-esb.log,service-esb-2015-04-15.log.zip etc. which i don't want to copy.

Comment: @user3259712 - sory.Changed the format on the wrong place.Now it should be ok.

Comment: echo off
echo %var%

for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(-6).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"`) do set yesterday=%%a
echo %yesterday%

SET logfiles=\\PWWAS0015\UMS_Logs\server1\ums\service-%yesterday%.log


copy %logfiles% C:\Users\l055094\Desktop\LogTest\GetFile\
pause .... I changed a bit and It worked beautifully now. Thanks for setting me the date and Can I schedule .cmd file in task scheduler so that i would get copied to my local daily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help you..

```
@echo
set source1="\\xxx" 
set dest="\\yyy"
pushd %source1%
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`"powershell (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"`) do set yesterday=%%~i
copy "yourfilename %yesterday%.log" "%dest%"
popd
```